# zipArchive in PHP is not working in server but on localhost runs and extracts the file

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have this application that fetches the data from `outlook` mail from `sendthisfile.com`.

Now in my `localhost` machine when I test the application, the `zipArchive` works well and the file extracts to my respective `localhost` folder. Now when I tried to run it on my server, the `zipArchive` is not working well. There is no error on it. There is a filename on `$zip->open($filename)`.

My question is why can't it extract on my server?

My code below:

```
$path = "my-folder/"; $zip = new ZipArchive; $resFile = $zip->open($filename);

if ($resFile === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($path);
    $zip->close();
    echo "Woot successfully extract $filename to $path";
    echo "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Error opening the file $filename";
}
```

Can someone help me figured this out?

Comment: What's your php version? Is the directory writable? Are you sure `zip` extension is enabled? You can check `phpinfo()` to verify. Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if it returns any error?

Comment: okay i will try to add ini_set('display_errors', 1); first to check

Comment: actually there is no error it goes to this line of code  echo "Woot successfully extract $filename to $path";

Comment: Make sure you write the correct path & filename, use `echo(__DIR__)` to check your current directory. Do you have write permission to path directory? Have you checked if 'zip' is enabled on your server?

Comment: you need to enable the ``ZipArchive`` module on your server. You'll not get any error even if it's not installed.

Comment: within a ``.php`` file add the following code: ``<?php phpinfo(); ?>`` and run the file and see if ``zip: enabled && zip version: xxx`` is printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose phpArchive has been enabled, and you have set a write permission to directory, it's likely to be `path` problem.

Try to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and try to run this code.

```
$path = "my-folder/";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$resFile = $zip->open($filename);

if ($resFile === true) {
    if ($zip->extractTo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$path) === false) {
        echo "Extract Failed!<br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Woot successfully extract $filename to $path<br/>";
    }
    $zip->close();
}
else{
    echo "Error opening the file $filename";
}
```

Comment: okay thanks for this i will add this document root code of yours. i already know the problem the server has no internet connection.

Comment: Your welcome! Have you solved your problem yet? What's the cause? Is it really because of internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the `ZIP` PHP extension on the server config. If you have a `cPanel` access, check the config in `PHP Selector`.